# Calculate the number of rows for a list of hive tables with pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I have created a spark program that retrieves the table names from a **Hive** database and then calculates the row count for a single table. However, I am trying to level this up by getting the row count for multiple tables, starting with 2 tables.

My spark code is:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import sys

def sql_count_rows(db,table):
    sql_query = """select count(*) from {0}.{1}""".format(db,table)
    return sql_query

db_name = sys.argv[1]

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("HiveTableRecordCount") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.sql("use {0}".format(db_name))
tables_df=spark.sql("show tables").collect()
tables_df=tables_df[0:2] #filter the first two tables
print("list content: ",tables_df)
print("list length: ",len(tables_df))
queryBuilder=""
#queryBuilder=queryBuilder + """select count(*) from {0}.{1}""".format(tables_df['database'], tables_df['tableName'])
#print("queryBuilder: ",queryBuilder)
loop_length=1
index=0
while loop_length < len(tables_df):
    queryBuilder =  sql_count_rows(tables_df[index]['database'], tables_df[index]['tableName'])#tables_df.foreach(lambda row: sql_count_rows(row,queryBuilder))
    queryBuilder = queryBuilder + "\nunion all \n"
    loop_length+=1
    index+=1

spark.sql(queryBuilder).show()
spark.stop()
```

To write the code I have inspired by [this](https://tunetotech.com/Post.aspx?post=8) article, *written in scala spark*.

When I execute the program I recieve back the following error:

> pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nmismatched input '' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'VALUES', 'TABLE', 'MAP', 'REDUCE'}(line 3, pos 0)\n\n== SQL ==\nselect count(*) from gr_mapping.active_contracts_stg_v2\nunion all \n^^^\n"

Could you please help to understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that while in Scala `\n` in String means a new line inside a variable, in Python it does not.

Basically, you can concatenate the statements without the `\n`:

````py
queryBuilder = queryBuilder + " union all "```
````